# How to disable "logd" logging?

Tags: logging, services, debug

The `/data/misc/logd/` directory is filled with 256 MB log files. Currently I don't need debug log files, so I would like to turn off logging.

Partial solution:
It seems I can turn off with the following command from terminal:

```
stop logd
```

But I think this will work until you restart the device.

Comment: Would this app do the same? See here: https://www.androidpolice.com/2014/09/04/stop-log-can-disable-all-android-logs-on-your-device-for-enhanced-privacy-and-performance-root-only/. Can be downloaded from here: https://www.apk4fun.com/link/19134/a/

Comment: Logcat is a reader of logs logd is Tue deamon process...as @irfan Latif stated disable or remove the init rc file

Answer (score 2):

`stop logd` or `setprop ctl.stop logd` makes `logcat` completely unavailable (which may break some apps/daemons) and isn't persistent across reboots. For permanently removing `logd` you need to delete `/system/etc/init/logd.rc` file which defines this `init` service. But it's not recommended.

The `/data/misc/logd/` directory is filled by `logcatd` which is a sub-service of main `logd` service. `256 MB` is the default size but can be changed if required <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/logcat/logcatd.rc#11))</sup>.

`logd` mainly covers the functionality of its desktop counterpart [syslogd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/syslogd), but also includes [klogd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/klogd) and partially [auditd](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/logd/README.auditd) to get logs from SELinux subsystem of kernel. However `logd` just reads from (RAM) memory buffers and doesn't save to persistent memory (files) by default. Reason is evident, these saved logs are of no use to a majority of users (as you), but too many write requests for these logs reduce flash memory (eMMC) life unnecessarily.

If one needs these logs as files, a separate service named `logcatd` (`logcat` daemon  which itself reads from `logd`) can save them to filesystem (on `userdebug` and `eng` builds only since Oreo <sup>([2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/558282bfe4650f7b249f5ba0a24d3a400d67b78b))</sup>). Going through the resources <sup>([3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/logcat/logcatd.rc), [4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/logd/README.property#14))</sup>, it's easy to control this service permanently (persistent across reboots) by setting property `persist.logd.logpersistd` (to `logcatd` or `clear`) or by using shell scripts `/system/bin/logpersist.[start|stop]`.